# How to make a Line follow a CGPoint in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, uigesturerecognizer, cgpoint, cgpath

I've created two CGPoints and a connecting line between them. My aim is the following: When I drag the second CGPoint with a SwiftUI DragGesture() the line will follow it (as if it's connected to it). At the moment the line doesn't follow the point. **How can I do that**?

[image]

Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Point : View {
    var position: CGPoint

    init(_ position: CGPoint) {
        self.position = position
    }
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 20)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .position(x: position.x, y: position.y)
    }
}
```

LineWithPoints.swift

```
struct LineWithPoints : View {
    @State var point1 = Point(.init(x: 0,   y: 0))
    @State var point2 = Point(.init(x: 450, y: 0))
    @State private var offset1 = CGSize.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        let lineBetween = LineBetween(pointPosition: $point2.position)
        
        ZStack {
            lineBetween.stroke(.red, lineWidth: 2)
            point1;               
            point2
                .offset(x: offset1.width, y: offset1.height)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { value in
                            let x = value.startLocation.x
                            let y = value.startLocation.y
                            let w = value.translation.width
                            let h = value.translation.height
                            offset1 = .init(width: (x + w) - point2.position.x,
                                           height: (y + h) - point2.position.y)
                        }
                )
        }
    }
    struct LineBetween : Shape, @unchecked Sendable {
        @Binding var pointPosition: CGPoint

        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            var path = Path()
            path.move(to: CGPoint.zero)
            path.addLine(to: pointPosition)
            path.closeSubpath()
            return path
        }
    }
}
```

ContentView.swift

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.ignoresSafeArea()
            LineWithPoints()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `let` instead of `@Binding` in the `Shape`. `@Binding` is a two-way connection the `Shape` doesn't write to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some things which could do with correction:

- Your struct `LineBetween` only accepts one point as argument, it assumes the other point is at (0,0).
- There is no need for a `Binding` because the point is read-only.
- Instead of creating the shape outside the `ZStack` and then stroking it inside the stack, it would perhaps be better to create it and stroke it inside the `ZStack` in one operation.
- The line is always being drawn to the position of point2, but this does not take the drag offset into consideration. This is the main reason why the line is not changing.
- At end of drag, you probably want to reset the offset and update the position of point 2, ready for another drag gesture.

Here is a revised version which addresses the points above. It draws the line to a target point. This is a computed property that combines the position of point 2 with the drag offset.

```swift
struct LineWithPoints : View {
    @State private var point1: Point
    @State private var point2: Point
    @State private var offset = CGSize()

    init(
        point1: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 200),
        point2: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 325, y: 200)
    ) {
        self._point1 = State(initialValue: Point(point1))
        self._point2 = State(initialValue: Point(point2))
    }

    struct LineBetween : Shape {
        let point1: CGPoint
        let point2: CGPoint

        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            var path = Path()
            path.move(to: point1)
            path.addLine(to: point2)
            path.closeSubpath()
            return path
        }
    }

    private var targetPoint: CGPoint {
        CGPoint(
            x: point2.position.x + offset.width,
            y: point2.position.y + offset.height
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            LineBetween(
                point1: point1.position,
                point2: targetPoint
            )
            .stroke(.red, lineWidth: 2)
            point1
            point2
                .offset(x: offset.width, y: offset.height)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { value in
                            offset = value.translation
                        }
                        .onEnded { _ in
                            point2 = Point(targetPoint)
                            offset = CGSize()
                        }
                )
        }
    }
}
```

[image: LineBetween]

Comment: Nice job Benzy Neez, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your **DragGesture** you're not changing the **pointPosition** which you pass to **LineBetween**, you only change the offset for the second circle. You can make the same var for the offset of the second circle and for the shape endpoint.